# How to get exact value from input in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to filter bootstrap dataTable using jquery. i'm done with it. but the problem is when i select `Male` it give results `female` also. jquery doesn't catch the exact word called `Male`.

Here is my jquery code and result

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table =  $('#example1').DataTable();

    $('#gender').on('change', function () {
      table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
    });
 });
```

this is my view when i select `Female`.
[Select Female](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf773.png)

This is my view when i select `Male`
[Select Male](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BJ5P.png)

So how i get the result only male when i select male.

Comment: Just to be clear, this has nothing to do with Bootstrap or jQuery. This is [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) functionality.

Comment: well, male is part of female, maybe you can pass in a regex like `/^male$/`?

Comment: how can i pass it to above jquery code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use the second parameter of the [search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) function to indicate that your query is a regex. You would then also have to indicate that you do not want to use the smart search functionality, which is the third parameter

```
const regExSearch = '^' + this.value + '$';
table.columns(1).search(regExSearch, true, false).draw();
```

this would include the whitespace before and after your input, so you might not need those.

The sample code I provided, is really just the code found in the documentation

Comment: ops. when i select male / female results is null.

Comment: @user3263347 Yeah, I guess it was mainly because the whitespace in front of it where not optional ;) I updated the answer, so feel free to check again

Comment: when i select male its null. but when i select female its getting the results.

Comment: Well, just add some demo code/data in your question, so we can reproduce your code and then I can check to update my answer to make it fitting

Answer (score 0):

Both gender values male/female have 'male' in the word so its searching in both cases. You can use `'\\b'+'this.value'+'\\b'` regex to exactly [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) the word. Check about `/b` [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
 $('#gender').on('change', function () {
      table.columns(1).search( '\\b'+'this.value'+'\\b' ).draw();
    });
```

Hope it helps.